# What tags should be used for SEO in simple blog posts?

Tags: seo, html, blog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best ways to increase your site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-your-sites-position-in-google)
>   [Order of HTML meta tags](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/11623/order-of-html-meta-tags)

I'm new to websites in general (which is why I'm starting on blogger) and am just curious as to which tags I should be using in my posts?

My posts generally include a title relevant to the keyword of my blog, an image, a video, my content, and a link to my twitter.

I don't really use any tags and someone mentioned that they may help for SEO. So I figured I would ask for some advice from people who know what they are doing.

**EDIT**

I apologize for not clarifying, I meant tags such as:

Header tag:

```
<h1>This is my title</h1>
```

Image tags with attributes:

```
<img src="keyword_image.jpg" width="100" height="78" ALT="this_shows_examples">
```

What other tags and attributes are ones I should use for a well put together website and SEO?

Comment: @toomanyairmiles I don't see how it is a duplicate? That person is talking specifically about <h1> where as I'm wondering what other tags and attributes may play a role in SEO and examples of how they should be done.

Comment: Basically that question contains everything you need to know. In essence, use heading tags, use them correctly, and use them sparingly. Expect attributes like title and alt to be useful to users and ignored by search engines.

Comment: @toomanyairmiles That answer doesn't cover attributes on image tags, or new HTML5 tags. This question could be used to capture the wisdom on those too.

Answer (score 1):

> My posts generally include a title relevant to the keyword of my blog, an image, a video, my content, and a link to my twitter.

Well, you essentially answered this yourself. Just follow simple semantic HTML rules and you will be fine.

- The title should be `<h1>` or `<h2>`, and no other elements should have this so it's clear which one is the lead.
- The image should specify `alt` and `title` attributes with proper keywords and description so it can be indexed, as well as height and width. If you can control the filename of the image make that descriptive as well. No `image.jpg`, instead `picture-of-pee-wee-herman.mpg`
- The video, depending on how you're embedding it, should also have a reasonable text description in the attributes, or at least the surrounding text. If you can control the filename of the video make that descriptive as well. No `movie1.mpg`, instead `dogs-playing-with-cats.mpg`
- Content should have basic HTML like `<p>` for each paragraph, `<blockquote>` for quotes, proper bulleted and numbered `<li>` lists, etecetera.
- The link to your twitter should be descriptive in the `alt` and `title` attributes, as well as the linked text. Avoid links like [click here](http://example.com) and instead try [follow me on twitter at @username](http://example.com)